# Form align - Fields are too far apart

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and have never worked with it(i know its sad) the space beetween my form inputs is too big check https://tadzik9634.000webhostapp.com/lest-sidebar.php 
I couldnt find a solution to align them so the space would be smaller here is my html code. Also the space bettween my radio buttons is massive.

```
<div class="container-form">
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
 <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="first_name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Name:</label>
 <div class="col-sm-4">
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="first_name">
 <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
<label for="last_name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">SurnameName: </label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="last_name">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $lastNameErr;?></span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="email" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Email: </label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="email">
<span class="help-block">Please Enter Your Email</span>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
</div>
</div>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="ironing" id="optionsRadios1" <?php if (isset($ironing) && $ironing=="Yes") echo "checked";?> value="Yes">Yes
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="ironing" id="optionsRadios2" 
<?php if (isset($ironing)&& $ironing=="No") echo "checked";?> value="No">No
</label>
<span class="help-block">Would Like Ironing?</span>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $ironingErr;?></span>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Romms" class="col-sm-4 control-label" >Number Of Rooms: </label>
<div class="col-sm-4">                                  
<input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" max="10" name="Rooms">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $RoomErr;?></span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Hours" class="col-sm-4 control-label" > Number hours: </label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<input  type="number" class="form-control input-sm" min="3" name="Hours">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $RoomErr;?></span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">    
<label for="description">Description of the House: </label> 
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <textarea name="description" rows="3" class="form-control input-sm" cols="10"></textarea>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $descriptionErr;?></span>
</div>
</div>
<input class="btn btn-default"type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't put the form fields (label and field) is separate columns, as you inherently get the column spacing.  Try using the bootstrap class `form-inline` to position your elements next to one another instead.

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="first_name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="first_name">
        <span class="error">* </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

Comment: That did it but my radio buttons are still acting weird any suggostions u check the same page for updated version

Comment: @WojtekT It is a setting in your CSS.  See my answer.

Comment: @WojtekT Your syntax for your radio buttons is incorrect.  You have a `label` tag surrounding both labels and both radio buttons.

Proper syntax is documented here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#checkboxes-and-radios

Comment: I see I got it sorted now!, Thank you guys!,

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your HTML is not correct. Wrap your bootstrap columns in `row` class and your `form-group` inside the column. Something like this -

```
<div class="row>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group>
            <label></label>
            <input type="">
            ....
        </div>
    </div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the following in your file 'lest-sidebar.php' line 9

```
label{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 210px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

The `width` is causing the issue where your radio buttons are spaces so far apart.

Try using the following instead of setting the width of your label:

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="first_name">Name:</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="first_name">
            <span class="error">* </span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but now the field are all over the place

Comment: I got it kind of working, Now i have nanother question how to align the fieldns and labels to the left?

Comment: you can use bootstrap class .text-left or .pull-left